# How do I install Python module given as .py file?

Tags: python

I do realize this is a noobish question, but I've been trying for an hour and I can't get it right.

So, I have a Python script which I'd like to modify a bit and play around with as a Python beginner. However, at the very beginning of the script, there's this:

```
from priodict import priority_dict
```

Now, I have a file named `priodict.py` that came with the script. But how do I make it available to the script so it can be included like that?

The Python manual has pages and pages on installing modules, but they all seem to refer to "packages" which are to be placed in certain directories etc. What do I do when I have just the .py file?

I know there is probably a banale one-sentence response to this, but I'm getting frustrated and I'm short on time so I decided to take the easy way out and ask Stack overflow about it.

It seems that, if I don't have the priodict.py file, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\scripts\dijksta.py", line 192, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\scripts\dijksta.py", line 185, in main
    D, _ = dijkstra(G, 1, v)
  File "C:\Python27\scripts\dijksta.py", line 139, in dijkstra
    Q = priority_dict() # est.dist. of non-final vert.
NameError: global name 'priority_dict' is not defined
```

If I place the file in the same directory as my script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\scripts\dijksta.py", line 2, in <module>
    from priodict import priority_dict
ImportError: cannot import name priority_dict
```

These are the files in question:

https://github.com/kqdtran/ADA1/tree/master/dijkstra

Comment: you might have changed `dijkstra.py` file. The code should not produce NameError (and it is unrelated to installing modules).

Comment: You're right, the error is indeed different when the files are in the same directory - but there's still an error. I've included the new error and a link to the files in the questions, if someone could have a high-level look at what might be wrong that would be great.

Comment: The only way you could receive that first error is if you removed or changed the `from...import` line. I don't know how you got the second error but I assume it's also because you changed something. Try using the original versions of the files without changing anything.

Comment: do you have another `priodict` module in `sys.path`? try `import priodict; print(priodict)` what path does it show?

Comment: There's no other priodict - and I'm currently using the original files and still getting the error.

Comment: remove `.pyc`, `pyo` files. Include `print(priodict)` output.

Comment: You're definitely using **something** that's not what's posted on the site you linked to.  There is no file there named `dijksta.py`, yet that is the file you have in your traceback.  You would have gotten a different error if you were in fact running the `dijkstra.py` posted on that site, because it uses a Python 3 feature which is a syntax error in Python 2, and it appears you're using Python 2.7.  Also, your first traceback shows that `dijksta.py` is at least 192 lines, which is longer than `dijkstra.py`.  What else is in `dijksta.py`?

Comment: dijksta was a spelling error:) As for the Python 3 feature, I fixed that error before posting here. It's all fixed now, thanks, I hadn't copied them properly as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the file in the same directory, and that will get you started. Seems you've figured out that much. If all you have is a .py file, that's what you're usually expected to do.

If you're unable to import a name from a module, it usually means that name doesn't exist in that module. Try:

```
import priodict
print dir(priodict)
```

Is `priority_dict` listed? If not, is there a similarly named attribute that might be what you're looking for? It may just be that the instructions given you were misspelled, like the _ wasn't needed.

If it fails on the import line, it may be that there's an error in the module code itself that must be corrected first. you'll get an error telling you roughly where it is.